# Is possible to export programmatically a highcharts chart?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to make some reports and mail them out, using the data that I have on the web pages that my server display.

Is there a way via code, to export the graph; so I can attach it in a mail? I see that is possible to save the graph as image, using the mouse, but I can't see how you can actually go via code and create a version of the graph as image.

Comment: You need to generate image and attach to email automatically or only get chart as image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

As you've noted it requires the export module, which is included by also having:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

The functionality you are looking for is the [`chart.exportChart` function](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.exportChart). It allows you to:

> Submit an SVG version of the chart to a server along with some parameters for conversion.

Which can simply mean saving it through a button click, as shown in [this simple JFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-exportchart/). The functionality of the button is then:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.exportChart();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. There is plenty information on highchartsjs site. Check this [article](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/52-serverside-generated-charts) and [examples](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-articles/news/56-improved-image-export-with-phantomjs) and [github scripts](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/exporting-server/phantomjs). This is basics. Of course you could use other combination. I personally use phantomjs with asp.net.